# hide overflow bottom content only

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

I'm making a small animation on a nav element but I'm running into a problem. The content of the animated div should only be visible on the top of the nav element and not bot. But the height of the animated div is bigger then the height of the nav element, so the animated div shows up at the bottom of the nav. I made a jsFiddle with the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/umc4c/

```
// Homepage navigatie fadeIn + contentblok animatie
$('#content_home').hide();
$('nav').hide().fadeIn(1200, function(){
    var result = $("#content_home").outerHeight();

    $('#content_home').animate({marginTop: -Math.abs(result)},1000);
    $("#content_home").css("display", "block");
});

// Homepage navigatie animatie + url click event
$('nav a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;

    $('nav').animate({
        marginTop: '-650px'}, 
        1000,
        function(){
            window.location = href;
        });
});
```

I did fix this problem now by giving the nav div a height of 650px and an overflow hidden. But that way seems very nasty and I don´t like it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use **slideDown** instead of **animation**.
This way the div will expand as it slides instead of just moving the div.

here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/umc4c/21/

*Note that you would have to change your css a bit. You would have to add position relative to your nav class. Then you have to add bottom:100%; to #content_home.

```
nav {
    margin-top:400px;
    width:500px;
    background-color:grey;
    height:120px;
    **position:relative;**
}
#content_home {
    padding:50px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    background-color:#000;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    color:#fff;
    **bottom:100%;**
}
```